# Python: Using two while loops to create grid. No for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm having trouble trying to get my while loop to keep looping until both conditions are met. I'm only supposed to use while loops or if-statements/booleans if necessary.

I'm trying to print the grid for a game of grid size LENGTH X WIDTH.
So suppose

```
LENGTH = 5
WIDTH = 6

def create_grid(grid):

    x = 0
    y = 0

    while x < WIDTH and y < LENGTH:
          table = print(grid[WIDTH * x + y] + '|')
          x +=1
          y +=1

    return table
```

How do I get the while loop to loop for both x +=1 and y +=1 for the expression above?
I'd want it so that it would print this expression

```
while y < LENGTH:
    print('|' + grid[(0) * WIDTH + y] + '|' + '|' + grid[(1) * WIDTH + y] + ...
    + '|' + grid[(all the way up to WIDTH - 1) * WIDTH + y] + '|')

    y += 1

return ###expression above
```

I put in brackets where I'd like to substitute the numbers for x, x+1,...all the way up to x = WIDTH - 1 (or x < WIDTH).

I suppose I could just concatenate the pieces like this, and use just one while loop like above, but say the grid dimensions were huge, writing out the whole grid would take up too much space.

Comment: Assigning the return value of `print` to a variable makes absolutely no sense as it is guaranteed to be `None` (unless you shadow the built in `print` function with something else). This means a statement like  `return print "something"` doesn't make sense either, as it returns `None` which is the default value. So you should make up your mind if the function should return the string or simply print it and return `None`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **normally** would do this with a `for` loop; I'd just use slicing:

```
def create_grid(grid):
    table = ''

    for y in range(0, LENGTH * WIDTH, WIDTH):
        table += '|'.join(grid[y:y+WIDTH]) + '\n'

    return table
```

With a `while` loop, where you do the incrementing yourself, you'd use:

```
def create_grid(grid):
    y = 0
    size = LENGTH * WIDTH
    table = ''
    while y < size:
        table += '|'.join(grid[y:y+WIDTH]) + '\n'
        y += WIDTH

    return table
```

Note that we just jump through the whole grid `WIDTH` steps at a time, and let `'|'.join()` to the per-row work. You can do that part in a loop too:

```
def create_grid(grid):
    y = 0
    size = LENGTH * WIDTH
    table = ''
    while y < size:
        x = 0
        while x < WIDTH:
            if x:
                table += '|'
            table += grid[y + x]
            x += 1
        table += '\n'
        y += WIDTH

    return table
```

To list the grid *by column* (so, transposed), you'd need to use:

```
def create_grid(grid):
    y = 0
    size = LENGTH * WIDTH
    table = ''
    while y < LENGTH:
        x = 0
        while x < size:
            if x:
                table += '|'
            table += grid[y + x]
            x += LENGTH
        table += '\n'
        y += 1

    return table
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! We haven't covered or are allowed to use methods, so the last example really helped. However, I need the string I input to go down the column rather than across the row, hence the x * LENGTH inside the index grid. I tried table += grid[y + (x * LENGTH)], but now I get a string index out of range. >_<

Comment: So if your grid was filled with the numbers 0 to 29, you want to print `0|5|10|15|20|25` then `1|6|11|16|21|26`, etc.? Because `WIDTH` and `LENGTH` and `x` and `y` can still be interpreted ambiguously, I'd love it if you added a sample `grid` list value and a sample of your expected output to your question.

Comment: Yes, so if I typed in create_grid('123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstu'). The output would be |1|6|b|g|l|q| and next line right underneath |2|7|c|h|m|r|.. and so on. Here x = WIDTH = 6, and y = LENGTH(or height) = 5.

Comment: @muros: Updated; the *outer* loop, `y`, then increments by 1 each time (to step through the columns instead of through the rows each outer loop), and the *inner* loop then increments in `LENGTH` steps to skip over the rows to the next one to find the same column in the next row.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pieters! I noticed you've been consistently giving me the best answers :) Do you take students? If you do, I'd love to hire you as my tutor! Let me know!!

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, a while loop is exactly the same as a for loop, except without the increment. So if you need to implement the loop using while, you just do it as you would with for loops, but do the incrementing yourself. So this means you just nest two whiles:

```
x = 0
table = ''

while x < WIDTH:
    y = 0
    while y < LENGTH:
        table += grid[WIDTH * x + y] + '|'
        y +=1
    table += '\n'
    x +=1

return table
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but the thing is the table comes up skewed when I do it this way. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I added a newline character: does that help?

Comment: hmm.. it just adds the '\n' as a string rather than a new line.

Comment: Well, you need to print the result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the two sample code given as example is that you are using only one loop.

One "trick" that may help to solve a (programming) problem is trying to describe how you will do the thing "by hand". Here, to plot the grid, one should draw cell from row 1 to row H of the first column, then do it again for column 2 and so on.

Here in pseuso-code:

```
HEIGHT = 5
WIDTH = 6

current_row = 0
current_column = 0

# Draw the first column
while current_row < HEIGHT:
    draw_cell(current_column, current_row)
    current_row += 1

# Draw next column column
current_column += 1
while current_row < HEIGHT:
    draw_cell(current_column, current_row)
    current_row += 1

# ...
# ... and so on until last column
current_column += 1
while current_row < HEIGHT:
    draw_cell(current_column, current_row)
    current_row += 1
```

Obviously there is a lot of repetition of the *same* code. This is calling for *nested* loops. That is your first loop inside an other loop:

```
HEIGHT = 5
WIDTH = 6

current_row = 0
current_column = 0

# For each column
while current_column < WIDTH:
    # Draw the column
    while current_row < HEIGHT:
        draw_cell(current_column, current_row)
        current_row += 1

    # The "inner" loop is done.
    # Time to go to the next column
    current_column += 1
```

Here I am using a `while` loop since it seems to be what you favor. But as other have already stated, the "natural" tool for this kind of thing is the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested loops, but I'm still not sure I understand your code, as it appears to overwrite the value of `table` on every loop.  Does this do the trick?

```
LENGTH = 5
WIDTH = 6

def create_grid(grid):

   x = 0
   y = 0

   table = ""

   while y < LENGTH:
      while x < WIDTH:
         table += grid[WIDTH * x + y] + '|'
         x +=1
      print "\n" ### if you want a new-line when y is incremented
      y +=1

   return table

print create_grid(grid)
```